# Как восстановить код без комита

Tags: git, git-pull

Подскажите пожалуйста. Создал я тестовую ветку в Idea локальную. Писал в ней код 4 дня. И без комита, сделал pull с gitlab и перешел на другую ветку. Восстановить код я так понимаю уже невозможно на моей тестовой ветке. Так как изменения все пропали

Comment: И idea ни разу не предупредила что вы сейчас  потеряете все изменения? Точно не было коммитов?

Comment: Посмотрите, может idea что-то схоронила https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

Comment: 3 месяца с гитом работаю.Нажал rollback и он все убрал при переходе на другую ветку.Буду все восстанавливать.

Comment: Очень сильно помогло спасибо огромное.В локальных логах есть файлы изменений.И с помошью них добавляешь обратно их в текущий проект

Comment: Коммитить всё надо бы научится на третий день. Сделал законченный кусок  правки — коммит, пошёл пообедать — коммит, закончился рабочий день — однозначно коммит. И неважно что там не работает, историю в гит проще переписать чем восстанавливать из редактора.